# How do I set button states of a Floating Action Button using xml?

Tags: android

I have a floating action button in an xml below and works without errors

**fragment_one.xml**

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnFloatMain"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    app:maxImageSize="80dp"
                    app:fabCustomSize="80dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/button_float_main"
                    />
```

However I wanted to set the button states of the floating action button when pressed so I created the xml below

**button_states_float_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        app:maxImageSize="80dp"
        app:fabCustomSize="80dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/button_float_main_pressed"/>
    <item
        app:maxImageSize="80dp"
        app:fabCustomSize="80dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/button_float_main"/>
</selector>
```

and modified my button xml to

**fragment_one.xml**

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnFloatMain"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/button_states_float_main"
                    />
```

but I don't think I'm setting it the right way since my app crashes now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
android:drawable="@drawable/button_float_main_pressed"
```

instead of

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/button_float_main_pressed"
```

in **selector**